# What is the Jacobian matrix of the following.

Tags: calculus

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \left(1−x−\frac y2\right)x
\\
\frac{dy}{dt} = \left(1- \frac x3−y\right)y
$$
I am unsure about his to take the partial derivatives of these differential equations

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (dx/dt) = 1-2x-y/2, & 
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (dy/dt) = -y/3 \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (dx/dt) = -x/2, &
  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (dy/dt) = 1 - x/3 -2y. \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: @Amzoti you removed your comment (presumably because you no longer think this is incorrect?) but left the downvote!?